# How to get the value of an attribute whose name is not a literal in xQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery

For example:

```
let $targetAtt "= "att1";

let $doc := <Xml att1 = "la", att2 = "la la">
```

So this works:

```
return $doc/@*[(name(.) = $targetAtt)]
```

But is a more succinct syntax possible?

For example: the following Does **not** work

such as

```
return $doc/@$targetAtt.
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

A path expression requires a literal NameTest.  There is no way around this.  Some implementations may provide an eval function, eg `eval(concat("$doc/@", $targetAtt))` but in general this is to be avoided if it can be at all helped.

The only way to tidy the syntax in vanilla XQuery is with a user defined function:

```
declare function local:attribute($node as node(), $name as xs:QName)
{
    $node/@*[name(.) = $name]
};

local:attribute($doc, $targetAtt)
```